# Yii Foreign key error on model save

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I have the following tables:

```
user
- id (PK)
- ...

autoresponder
- id (PK)
- ...

user_autoresponder
- user_id (PK, FK to user.id)
- autoresponder_id (PK, FK to autoresponder.id)
```

In AutoresponderController I have

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Autoresponder;

    if(isset($_POST['Autoresponder']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Autoresponder'];

        if($model->save()) {
            UserAutoresponder::assignToUsers($model);
            $this->redirect(array('myadmin', 'cid'=>$model->category_id));
        }
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

and in the UserAutoresponder model I have:

```
public static function assignToUsers($autoresponder)
{
    $users = Yii::app()->db->createCommand()
        ->select('id')
        ->from(User::tableName())
        ->where('account_status > 0')
        ->queryAll();

    foreach ($users as $user) {

        $ua = UserAutoresponder::model()->findByPk(array(
                                            'user_id'=>$user['id'],
                                            'autoresponder_id'=>$autoresponder->id
                                        ));

        if (!$ua) {
                $t = new UserAutoresponder;
                $t->user_id = $user['id'];
                $t->autoresponder_id = $autoresponder->id;
                $t->save();
        }
    }
}
```

When I go to create an autoresponder, it errors with:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row:
>   a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`lead-manager`.`crm_user_autoresponder`, CONSTRAINT
>   `crm_user_autoresponder_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`autoresponder_id`)
>   REFERENCES `crm_autoresponder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE
>   CASCADE)

Given that the autoresponder has already been created and has been assigned an id, that I'm using the list of users already in the `user` table, and that I'm *also* checking if the record exists how is the query failing?

This works on my local machine and on the test server but not live.

Answer (score 0):

It is the constraint on *autoresponder_id* that fails. 
Check the **$autoresponder->id** value on your production environment : it may be null. If this is the case, then your production database does not fit your dev/test databases. Maybe the autoincrement for the PK has not been activated on the *autoresponder* table ?

Comment: Unfortunately if I `var_dump($autoresponder)` in `UserAutoresponder::assignToUsers()` I can see the autoresponder id has been assigned correctly.

Comment: Do you actually see the new autoresponder in your table ? Could you show us the sql query string ?

Comment: Yes, the responder is created in the table, it's available for editing/deleting etc.
How do I get the query string along with the bound values? It's not displayed in the error log.

Comment: You should find it in the application log (in the protected/runtime folder). Set the log level to 'trace' in your configuration before running the script.

Comment: `Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`lead-manager`.`crm_user_autoresponder`, CONSTRAINT `crm_user_autoresponder_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`autoresponder_id`) REFERENCES `crm_autoresponder` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE). The SQL statement executed was: INSERT INTO `crm_user_autoresponder` (`signature`, `user_id`, `autoresponder_id`) VALUES (:yp0, :yp1, :yp2).`

Doesn't show the bound values though (haven't found a way in Yii to do that) but I'm positive $autoresponder->id isn't null.